# How can I design a program to construct Legendre polynomials in Maple 13

Tags: maple, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

I'm a new user of Maple 13. I'm trying to design a program to illustration the progress of construct Legendre polynomials for my friends by using Maple. I've search on Google and found an algorithm for Mathmetica in here [Construct Legendre polynomials in Mathmetica](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/legendrepoly/LegendrePolyMod/Links/LegendrePolyMod_lnk_14.html), but I don't know how to write it in Maple.

Can someone help me some basic steps?

Answer (score 3):

`orthopoly[P](n,x)` is the $n$'th Legendre polynomial evaluated at $x$.

If you want to construct them yourself, you could use the recurrence

$$ \eqalign{P_{{n}} \left( x \right) &={\frac { \left( 2\,n-1 \right) xP_{{n-1}}
 \left( x \right) }{n}}-{\frac {\left( n-1 \right) P_{{n-2}}
 \left( x \right) }{n  }}\cr
P_0(x) &= 1,\; P_1(x) = x\cr} $$

For example (to have the first 20 as expressions in $x$)

```
P[0]:= 1:
P[1]:= x:
for n from 2 to 20 do
   P[n]:= expand((2*n-1)*x*P[n-1]/n -(n-1)*P[n-2]/n) 
end do;
```

Or if you prefer to define them as functions:

```
P[0]:= x -> 1;
P[1]:= x -> x;
for n from 2 to 20 do
   P[n]:= unapply(expand((2*n-1)*x*P[n-1](x)/n - (n-1)*P[n-2](x)/n), x)
end do;
```